# Flutter "Create 2 missing Overrides" bug?

Tags: flutter

When I try adding missing Overrides with Quick fix e.g. here: `class CirclePainter extends CustomPainter {}`, the result is completely buggy:

```
class CirclePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canva canva canvas, Si Si Size size) {
      // TODO: implement paint
    }
  
    @override
    bool shouldRepa(Canvas canvan canvas, Sigate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Not a big problem here but when I want to add 10 or more missing overrides I have to change every single one per hand.

Comment: I'm lost... it's not mandatory to override all the methods.. what do you mean with "buggy"?

Comment: With "buggy" I mean that the formatting is completely trash: "Si Si Size size". This happens when I Create the missing methods with the help of quick fix.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? It's the first time that I see that!

Comment: Im using vs code

Comment: Try to close VS code and open it again to see if it's a temporary glitch. You could also see if there is an upgrade for dart plugin

Comment: Already tried that. And its not only that one class. It happens as soon as I try creating 2 or more Overrides with Quick fix